# How to store data client side?

Tags: eclipse, html, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a web app using eclipse and gwt. I need to store some data. If I was building this for android, I'd use an sqlite db. But I'm making this for a Chrome Packaged App, the data needs to be stored with the client and remain there. I can't think of what to search for, does anybody have an example or tutorial or guidance? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use HTML5, **[Local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)** will suit you best.

More info [here](http://html5tutorial.net/tutorials/working-with-html5-localstorage.html) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/).

Answer (score 1):

GWT actually already has this.

Check it out:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this as HTML 5 so I suggest trying [localStorage?](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome browser supports sqlite as well; should work more or less straight out of the box (at least it does for my apps). At least on modern Chrome releases.

Comment: If you're downvoting this answer, feel free to comment on why. He states he prefers using sqlite, and I tell him it's available for Chrome (including Chrome Packaged Apps) as well (contrary to his faulty assumption), and this gets downvoted because ...?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're building a Chrome Packaged App, you can use any storage [API supported by Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_other.html). That includes Web Storage and Web Database, as others have already said, but also (on recent versions of Chrome, so it depends on your schedule) File API and Indexed DB.

Everything you can do in JS, you can do it in GWT.

As others have said, GWT gives you built-in access to Web Storage. The [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project brings you Web Database. If you prefer the File API or Indexed DB, then you can use JSNI to access them from your GWT code (unless someone else already wrote a wrapper library).

If you choose the Web Database (which is just SQLite accessible from JS), you might want to set the [`unlimitedStorage` permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions).

Comment: IndexedDB just isn't there yet; essential functionality like "deleteDatabase" is missing from Chrome at least, and the otherwise excellent debug console in Chrome does not show any IndexedDB instances. Use localStorage (if a key value store is enough), or WebSQL (effectively SQLite).